# Как сконфигурировать Freescale Vybrid CPU IOMUX для сигналов IO и CLC?

Tags: linux, kernel, arm

Я прочитал в Reference Manual для Freescale VF50, что этот процессор поддерживает интерфейс UART для связи со Smart Card.

Однако в руководстве нет ни слова о том, какие ноги и в каком режиме IOMUX надо конфигурировать для сигналов IO и CLK.

Заранее спасибо,
Дмитрий.

Comment: О-па, а суффикс NXP означает, что вы на них работаете?

Comment: NXP писал в тэги, случайно попал не туда. Я не понял как тут на сайте поправлять. Заодно бы перевел...